# How to resolve "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" Error in Rails 4 form_for in Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a new user form that I am placing in a Bootstrap Modal, I have the modal in the application.hmtl.erb file as it only loads out of the nav bar.

When I now log into my app, I immediately get **an error that says:**

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Here is a screenshot of the error screen:

[image]

**My Controller:**

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def new_user
    authorize! :manage, User
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create_user
    @user = User.new(permitted_params.user)
    authorize! :manage, User
    @user = User.find_by_admin_ident(params[:user_id])
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'User has been successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'There was a problem creating this user, please try again.' }
    end
  end

end
```

**My Routes:**

```
  as :user do
    get "admins/new_user" => "admins#new_user", as: :admins_new_user
    post "admins/create_user" => "admins#create_user", as: :admins_create_user
  end
```

**This is the form in the modal:**

```
  <!-- Start - Modles -->
    <!-- Start - New User Creation -->
    <%= form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="userCreate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create New System User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                <% end %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :f_name %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :middle_name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :m_name %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :l_name %>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :date_of_birth %><br />
                <%= f.date_field :dob %>
              </div>

              <br />
              <%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize}) %>
              <br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <%= f.submit "Create User", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- End - New User Creation -->
  <!-- End - Modles -->
```

**And here is the full stack trace:**

```
ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty:
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:438:in `form_for'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:103:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4479294121403992034_70212707790400'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/developer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:30:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:36:in `default_render'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:181:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:31:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  actionview (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/digestor.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (3.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.0.rc1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Please let me know if you need any further info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think its happen if you get `nil` user object  and how can you access admin_controller instance variable in main layout ??

Comment: you can use `before_filter` in application controller to set @user object

Comment: so before_filter am i authorizing users? or admins?

Comment: ive never ventured down this path before..

Comment: you are accessing @user object in `application.html.erb` and setting up `@user` object in admin_controller

Comment: yes I am, so would i just use the before_filter @user in the application file like you mentioned above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115903/discussion-between-uzaif-and-shawn-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

This error visible when you pass nil object to `form_for`

In your case you are setting up `@user` instance variable in `admin_controller` and you are fetching `@user` variable in `application.html.erb` layout which cause is `nil` user object

your problem can be solve with `before_filter` 
You just need to put `before_filter` in application controller and make method which will setup @user object

```
before_filter :set_user
def set_user 
 @user = User.new 
end
```

Hope it solve your issues